# Get id from a post php

Tags: php, html

So, i want to get id from `$_POST["id"]` when i push a button in a table

```
<form action="dosomething.php" method="post">
<td> <?php echo $row["id"]; ?> </td>
<td> <button>Do something</button> </td>
</form>
```

is that even possible?

thanks for any answers and help

Comment: You can use `<td><input name="id" type="submit" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"></td> `

Comment: But generally it is more favourable to use javascript and ajax requests for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: FYI: You can not nest form and table call elements this way, that is not allowed in HTML. Either the form has to go around the complete table, or be contained within a single table cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is.

You will need to set a hidden input somewhere inside your form tags, like :

```
<form action="dosomething.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $row["id"]; ?>" />
<td> <?php echo $row["id"]; ?> </td>
<td> <button onclick="this.form.submit();">Do something</button> </td>
</form>
```

This is not an elegant code and you should probably consider using javascript, especially if you have a lot rows and buttons.